# calculating mac for wsp header

Tags: gsm, hmac, ota, wbxml

I am trying to get mac value for wsp header, according documentation S40 OMA client Provisioning doc, page 36 of Appendix B (http://sorrytesting.googlecode.com/files/Series_40_DP_2_0_OMA_Client_Provisioning_v1_3_en.pdf)
1) I 've got this wbxml:
1. I considered the below XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE wap-provisioningdoc PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD PROV 1.0//EN" “http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/prov.dtd">
<wap-provisioningdoc version="1.0">
<characteristic type="NAPDEF">
<parm name="NAPID" value="inet"/>
<parm name="NAME" value="InternetNAPDEF"/>
<parm name="BEARER" value="GSM-GPRS"/>
<parm name="NAP-ADDRESS" value="internet"/>
<parm name="NAP-ADDRTYPE" value="APN"/>
<parm name="INTERNET"/>
</characteristic>
<characteristic type="APPLICATION">
<parm name="APPID" value="w2"/>
<parm name="TO-NAPID" value="inet"/>
<characteristic type="RESOURCE">
<parm name="URI" value="http://wap.krak.dk"/>
<parm name="STARTPAGE"/>
</characteristic>
</characteristic>
<characteristic type="BOOTSTRAP">
<parm name="NAME" value="Sonofon Browser"/>
</characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

2)I have got WbXML file:

```
030B6A05 696E6574 00C54601 C6550187 ..j. inet ..F. .U..
11068300 01870706 03496E74 65726E65 .... .... .Int erne
744E4150 44454600 01871006 AB018708 tNAP DEF. .... ....
0603696E 7465726E 65740001 87090689 ..in tern et.. ....
01871401 01C60001 55018736 00000603 .... .... U..6 ....
77320001 87220683 0001C600 01590187 w2.. .".. .... .Y..
3A000006 03687474 703A2F2F 7761702E :... .htt p:// wap.
6B72616B 2E646B00 01871C01 0101C656 krak .dk. .... ...V
01870706 03536F6E 6F666F6E 2042726F .... .Son ofon Bro
77736572 00010101 wser ....
Series
```

3)With help of HashCalc I have got sha1 string d0e034c0864e5e72dfea6e3b43022a32b239af76

4) In hex it is : 64306530333463303836346535653732646665613665336234333032326133326232333961663736

But in document it is : 4430453033344330383634453545373244464541
3645334234333032324133324232333941463736

How they did it?